# Biweekly, bimonthly, semi-confused

Tags: prefixes, confusables, recurring-events

There seems to be a fair amount of confusion surrounding the meaning of the prefix `bi` when used with units of time measurement. Biweekly, according to dictionary.com, can mean either "occurring twice weekly," or "occurring once every two weeks." Falling within the same realm of confusion are bimonthly and biannually.

As of late, it seems that we've begun replacing the `bi` prefix with `semi` when the intended meaning is "occurring twice within," while continuing to use the former when the intended meaning is "occurring once every other." Though this is a step in the right direction, there still seems to be confusion around proper usage.

Whose genius idea was it to start using the `bi` prefix to mean two very different things? If my employer told me my pay periods were bimonthly, should I assume they meant semimonthly or once every other month?

Comment: This question sounds an awful lot like [peeving disguised as a question](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq). What are you actually asking here? The identity of the single person who coined a novel usage?

Comment: I interpret the core of this question as asking "am I right to think that bi- words are currently ambiguous? do most people take them as `twice an x`, or as `once every two x`?". This could give helpful answers to potential visitors from the internets.

Comment: @Cerebrus Yup, I agree. We should interpret this post in the most charitable light, and I think there is a germ of a good question here...

Comment: Clearly the _Whose genius idea..._ rhetorical question is peeving.  If this entry is to be kept, perhaps that part should be toned down or removed.

Comment: I'm most disappointed that the title wasn't "biweekly, bimonthly, bi-curious."  :-)

Comment: As you showed, the *bi-* prefix is ambiguous in this context, so there is no answer for your second question.  You can't assume either.  (And your first question, of course, is actually just a complaint :)

Comment: The question isn't meant to be rhetorical or even peeving, but rather which definition should be considered _most_ accurate. While I can see why you might confuse this for a mini-rant, there were two intentions: to learn the _proper_ usage of the `bi` prefix, and to help other confused persons searching for the potential differences between bimonthly and semimonthly. I suppose I did indeed get off track, and as such the question did come across a little like a peeve.

Comment: @Chris: The first actual *question* in your post starts with "Whose genius idea…" So I don't see how you can claim that the question is about "which definition should be considered most accurate". If that question was what you meant, that's what you should have said. :-)

Comment: Well I, for one, wish that the luminaries of this stackexchange, who chose to chide the OP for his turn of phrase, would have concentrated their collective energies on providing more depth in the form of a useful answer. The question (as interpreted by Cerberus) is a very valid one, and I'm sure the community would be enriched if the cognoscenti were to provide a more definitive exposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious distinction is between *biannual* and *biennial* which although originally cognate from Latin and Italian now seem to have distinct common meanings: *twice a year* and *every two years* respectively, even though Wiktionary discourages [biannual](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/biannual).

So for weeks and months all you need to do is wait for two forms to arise and then wait for people to decide which is which.   *Semi-* for "half a ...", i.e. "twice a ...", looks a sensible approach.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the prefixes, `bi` means `two`, and `semi` means `half`. But the question here, is does that refer to the number of occurrences in the given period, or the number of periods per occurrence? I think that's where the confusion came in, and apparently the coiners of the words were not consistent.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure how we can help to reduce the confusion.

Comment: If used as the Romans would, *bi-x* would mean "once every two x".