# "Biweekly", "bimonthly", "biannual", and "bicentennial": dual usage and rationale

Tags: meaning, prefixes, recurring-events

What do lengths of time with the "bi" prefix mean"? I have understood *bicentennial* as once every two hundred years, but *biannual* as meaning twice a year. Do *biweekly* and *bimonthly* mean *twice a week* or *month*, or *once every two weeks* or *months*?

If this prefix is not used consistently, is there any rationale as to why it isn't?

Comment: There was some discussion of this [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15756/biweekly-bimonthly-semi-confused), though the question was closed.

Comment: If you want to say that something is every two weeks, you can say that it is *fortnightly*. See http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/fortnight?q=fortnightly

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*Bi-* **usually** means "every two" (as in "every two [weeks/months/years, etc.]." But it can also mean "twice every [week/month/year, etc.]." To avoid confusion, I save *bi-* for "every two" and use *semi-* to mean "twice every." I wish everyone did.

Comment: Surely, to avoid confusion, one is sadly forced to bow to peer pressure and use _every two_ for "bi"?

Answer (score 6):

The meanings of the prefix [*bi*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/bi-) are:

- Occurring twice in every one: *biannual*, *bimonthly*.
- Occurring once in every two: *bicentennial*, *biennial*.
- Lasting for two: *biennial*, *biennium*.

The meaning of *biannual*, for example, could be either the first or the second.

Comment: It looks clear and concise, but is misleading. _biannual_, for instance, should be shown to be in both [your] categories 'a' and 'b'.

Answer (score 3):

In a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105869/whats-the-best-english-word-for-6-months-in-this-group-daily-weekly-quarterl#105869) which was closed as a duplicate of this question, Steward Godwin Jornsen asked:

> I've had some trouble coming up with a one word adjective for 6 months. ... I've thought of *semi-annually* and *bi-annually* ... Could there be a better word for it?

While either of the adverbs *[semiannually](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semiannually#Adverb)* (“In a semiannual manner, twice yearly”) or  *[biannually](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/biannually#Adverb)* (“Twice per year”) might serve, you could also consider *twice-yearly* and *half-yearly*, which fairly transparently mean twice a year and every six months, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, jwpat7. Voted you up for the good thoughts. That could do, I really need a one worder for 6 months (half-a-year) like: daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly, 6monthly, yearly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

biweekly = every two weeks
bimonthly = every two months
biennially = every two years
semiweekly = twice a week
semimonthly = twice a month
semiannually = biannually = twice a year

Comment: Then what are the words for twice a week, month, year, or century?

Comment: This answer is technically incorrect. [Biweekly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/biweekly) can, and often does, mean twice a week. [Bimonthly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bimonthly) also has a similar double-meaning.

Comment: @MrHen is right. Also, I'd prefer *biannual* to *semiannual*, although both are equally valid. Putting on my British hat, I'd certainly use *fortnightly* to mean *every two weeks*, instead of *biweekly*, in order to prevent any ambiguity.

Comment: Wearing British hats can also give rise to ambiguity. My wife has two monthly pensions. One she receives every calendar month, the other bifortnightly.



  

However, I would go with Collins' putting the calendar month as the principal polyseme rather than the AHDEL's attempt to be all-inclusive resulting in the loose: **1** _A unit of time corresponding approximately to one cycle of the moon's phases, or about 30 days or 4 weeks_.

Comment: Answer is technically, etymologically, & logically correct. Commenter's objections are based on usage, which could be mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 2):

From Handbook of Technical Writing, 5th Edition (Brusaw, Alred, Oliu):

> When used with periods of time, bi means "two" or "every two". Bimonthly means "once in two months"....When used with periods of time, semi means "half of" or "occurring twice within a period of time." Semimonthly means "twice a month".

I thought there was a note that said, "avoid this word because it is confusing," but that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

The annual values were disaggregated into biannual values. Then the ... (proscribed) Occurring every two years; biennial. 1993, World ... is unclear. Semiannual can be used to mean "every six months", and biennial to mean "every two years"

Answer (score 1):

This is why scientists were tasked to put a man on the moon and not English teachers.  Can you imagine if the definition of the rocket coordinates had dual meanings and changed arbitrarily on the whim of a user?

The prefix "bi-" comes from the Latin "bis" meaning "twice".  Substituting for "bi-" we have: bi-weekly = twice-weekly; bi-annually = twice annually.

Time for all of the English gurus to get together and settle this once and for all!

Comment: English is horrible: "biweekly" much more commonly means "every two weeks" while "biannually" much more commonly means "twice a year", yet it is somewhat acceptable to swap them. It's best to avoid these terms. Happily, "semiweekly" and "semiannually" both always mean twice a week/year, so by your usage, you should always favor semi- over bi-.