# A word for "every two days"

Tags: single-word-requests, recurring-events

Is there an adjective that means "every two days", i.e. is to a day as *biennial* is to a year?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In regular conversation, the phrase is simply *every other day*. Technically, however, one could use **bidiurnal**. It appears the word may have been coined by [Ursula M. Cowgill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursula_Cowgill) in her 1965 paper, *[A bidiurnal cycle in the feeding habit of Perodicticus potto](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC219682/)*, from which I quote thus (emphases mine):

> A definite *bidiurnal* cycle exists; the data corrected for natural loss are shown in Figure 1. The χ<sup>2</sup>
>   for the *48-hr periodicity* is highly significant (χ<sup>2</sup> = 188).
>   <sub>*Cowgill, PNAS, 420 (1965)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I learnt the word _diurnal_ as well.

Comment: I'd be a bit careful about actually *using* "bidiurnal", given that it's a neologism with no real currency, that might easily be misunderstood to mean "twice a day". Interestingly, medical prescriptions often use **QOD**, which seems to be a bowlderisation of **QD** (Latin "quaque die" - *every day*) with the **O** standing for "Other" added in the middle.

Comment: @Tim: You're welcome. At first, I was going to say that no single word existed for this. But I already knew the word *diurnal*. Then I thought, if there was such a word, it could be *biurnal*, but no luck! I didn't want to think of the possibility of having *bi-* and *di-* together in a word (it turns out that the *di* here is not the suffix that means *two*), but I searched for it, anyway, and, lo and behold, here was this paper to back me up. The word is probably common in botanical (or scientific) circles but not in regular conversation. It may well be that a synonym exists in astronomy.

Comment: @Fumble: I just realised that as well -- bidaily and biannual mean "twice a day" and "twice a year". Didn't know of *QOD*, thanks.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But the same ambiguity occurs in *bimonthly*, which could either mean *twice a month* or *every two months*; an also *biweekly*, which could either mean *twice a week* or *every two weeks*.

Comment: @Tim: *Bidaily* is not a formal coinage; *biannual* strictly means *twice a year*, while *biennial* means *once every two years*.

Comment: You may want to check out this question: [“Biweekly”, “bimonthly”, “biannual”, and “bicentennial”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18540/biweekly-bimonthly-biannual-and-bicentennial).

Comment: @Jimi: I know the difference between _biannual_ and _biennial_. Only the former is (in a sense) composed by prefixing _bi_- to _annual_, which seems to imply that prefixing _bi-_ to such a period would double it. This is also how _bidaily_ is used.

Comment: @Jimi: My point was that *bidiurnal* is an undesirable word both because it has no currency and because of the scope for misunderstanding. I fail to see how the existence of similar words also prone to misinterpretation or genuine ambiguity strengthens the case for supporting this wretched neologism.

Comment: @Tim: Sorry if my previous comment sounded patronizing. I understand the construction of *bidaily*, and I think it is perfectly valid, except you won't find it in a dictionary, just as you won't find *bidiurnal*. It seems that the Latinate or Germanic roots are used, depending on which sounds better. Hence, *biannual* instead of *biyearly*. *Bidaily* definitely sounds more awkward than *bidiurnal*. We use *bimonthly* only because *bimenstrual/bimensual* would not work for obvious reasons. *Biweekly* has also become standard because *bihebdomadal* would simply be incongruously long and obscure!

Comment: @Fumble: I'm not here to argue about the desirability of the word ;) Tim asked if there *is/was* a [single-word] adjective that means *every two days*, and I simply provided an answer—a word that was used in a duly vetted scientific paper. And note that I suggested *every other day* as the standard phrase. Come to think of it, I actually like *bidiurnal*. We'll probably forever disagree on this :) I would hold, however, that your disapproval of the word, based on its perceived ambiguity, is unfair and unfounded, as *bimonthly* and *biweekly* have the same problem!

Comment: @Jimi: Fair enough. You managed to find the word, so undeniably it does exist in some sense, even if it's not defined in any dictionaries or recorded in the vast Google NGram corpus. There's no point in arguing about that - my point is simply that I wouldn't use it, and by implication I'd recommend others to avoid it. In the end, if people want to, they will use it regardless of my opinion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Point taken!

Comment: I just checked Google Books for [pre-1965 written instances of ***bidiurnal.***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bidiurnal%22&biw=1258&bih=623&sxsrf=AOaemvJ5_mTb04iBAOSMheWmNoVQt8KhPQ%3A1640630867078&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1800%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1964&tbm=bks) There are plenty, and it's pretty obvious most if not all of them relate to ***the bidiurnal flow and ebb of the tides*** - which are ***twice a day***, not ***every two days***. This answer remains misleading even 10 years later! :)

Answer (score 2):

The abbreviation QOD or QAD (from Latin mean Quaque Alternis Die") means 'every other day' or 'every two days'.

Modern style in medical situations recommends using using the spelled out English 'every other day' because the Latin abbreviations are often misread.

Comment: [List of abbreviations used in medical prescriptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_abbreviations_used_in_medical_prescriptions)

Comment: it says `q.a.d` for Lat. `quaque alternis die`

Answer (score 2):

You could use "alternate".

> I used to post on Instagram **daily**, but now I've switched to posting on **alternate days**.
> P.S Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, though not to answer your question directly, for phrases of the type:

> A definite **bidiurnal** cycle exists...

it is perfectly natural formal English to say

> A definite **two-day** cycle exists...

Answer (score 0):

The Merriam-Webster Collegiate Dictionary, eleventh edition, defines 'tertian' as 'recurring at approximately 48-hour intervals -- used of malaria'.

It could cause confusion, though. Since Latin 'tertius' means 'third', you would think it should mean 'every third day', and some dictionaries simply define it that way. But that's because the Romans included the current day in naming intervals. One of the dictionaries cited at https://www.definitions.net/definition/Tertian clarifies it by defining the noun 'tertian' thus: 'a disease, especially an intermittent fever, which returns every third day, *reckoning inclusively*, or in which the intermission lasts one day'. My italics.

Comment: _The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language_, fifth edition (2010) offers this reconciliation of the "every 48 hours" meaning and the "every third day" meaning of **tertian**: "Recurring every other day or, when considered inclusively, every third day: _a tertian fever_." That is, the fever recurs on the third day, counting the initial occurrence of the fever as happening on the first day of the sequence.