# "each day" → "daily"; "every other day" →?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, time, analogy, recurring-events

Is there an adjective that means "every other day"? I found "bidaily" but it seems to mean "twice a day", not "every second day" (not even both as "biweekly" does).

I'd need this word to very concisely describe a questionnaire by its issuing frequency.

Comment: What’s wrong with “every other day”?

Comment: Or perhaps "on alternate days"?

Comment: @tchrist I'd very much prefer a one-word solution. And "every-other-day" isn't much help. "The every-other-day questionnaire" ... it feels really cumbersome. And it doesn't fit in a small table cell :/

Comment: @Christian in that case I'd probably go for _alternating questionnaire_, but that might also not fit 100% in your context. If you need a short phrase, you will have to cut some corners somewhere.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22318/a-word-for-every-two-days

It seems your choices include bidiurnal or 'QOD', which is used in medical prescriptions.

Comment: Thanks! I would argue that this should be an answer but then again, the whole question seems to be a duplicate so it should be marked accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no one word. The best you can do is "alternate day." An alternate day questionnaire is a questionnaire that appears every other day.

Comment: Sounds quite ok, despite being two words :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There would be two words: *semidaily* and *bidaily*.  If you think one of them means twice a day, then you should think the other means every other day.

Comment: I don't think anything. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bidaily That word is already hard to find in dictionaries. "Semidaily" is almost nonexistent outside Urban Dictionary. You don't seem very sure yourself if I might say so.

Comment: When you ask for nonexistent words, you may get strange answers.

Comment: Oh, I thought I might get the answer "Sorry, there is no such word in the English language" which is not at all strange. If you read my question carefully, you might notice that I asked in fact for the very existence of such a word. I got downvoted nonetheless which I in turn find strange.

Comment: *Semi-* is half, so *semi-daily* means on the half-days. The OED says it means twice a day, which is the same thing.

Comment: @tchrist Isn't that the whole "biannually" debate again? Yes, semiannually seems to mean "twice a year" for almost everyone. But biannually maddeningly means the same thing to many, while it means "every other year" for others.

Comment: I believe that it might take many years before the use of semi and bi to be used for "every other x" versus "twice Per x" is clear enough to be certain that everyone understands when it's not clear from context. That does not stop people from using them. In many situations it is quite clear from context