# Term for "Every 2 weeks"?

Tags: single-word-requests, recurring-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any words I can use to disambiguate “biweekly”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50658/are-there-any-words-i-can-use-to-disambiguate-biweekly)

Is there a term two designate a frequency of "every two weeks", like "weekly" for "every week".

Comment: Biweekly would also work, but there can be some ambiguity over whether you mean twice a week, or every two weeks.

Comment: You can use 'two-week' word. Eventually 'semiweekly'.

Comment: @kenorb "semiweekly" would pretty much unambiguously mean "twice a week".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Fortnightly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fortnightly): Happening every two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Biweekly, as you can see at the [Cambridge online dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/biweekly?q=biweekly).

Comment: I was pretty sure biweekly meant "twice a week".

Comment: Generally all these prefixes have some ambiguity to them. "Bi-annual" can mean either "semiannual" (once every half-year, or twice every year) or "biennial" (once every two years).