# What does bimonthly really mean?

Tags: meaning, recurring-events

Does the bi prefix mean that it is every second month or twice a month?

Comment: It works both ways: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bimonthly.

Comment: So it is ambiguous?

Comment: It's confusing enough that the term is best avoided altogether.

Comment: Semi-monthly would be more syntactically correct for twice a month, but bimonthly is the one commonly used.  As RK01 points out, bimonthly should mean every two months, but with usage it has come to mean both.

Comment: Discussed already here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18540/biweekly-bimonthly-biannual-and-bicentennial

Comment: I just wonder why that thread did not come up when I asked the question?

Comment: @NeilMeyer: I don't know, but if I put "bimonthly" in the search box, the second result is the previously-answered question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the prefix means two, so bimonthly can mean twice a month or every second month. Always use context, look at the sentence or the surrounding paragraph. That should help you figure out which meaning is being used.