# Is there a word to describe period types?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, what would be a generic term to categorize these words: *daily, monthly, yearly, bimonthly, quarterly* etc.

The word should mean "type of period between reoccurring events". One type is "daily", the other type is "monthly", etc. To summarize: I need a word that these examples are instances of.

Comment: Are you looking for the word *periodic*, or perhaps *periodicity*? When you say "period *type*", do you mean *duration*?

Comment: @Lawrence these words are all examples of period types. I need a word that these examples are instances of.

Comment: I'm still unsure what you mean by *type*. Please [edit] your question to explain.

Comment: The hypernym is _frequency adverbs_; your examples of 'types' surely indicate that each member has its own sub-class.

Comment: Is this about picking the name of something for a computer program?

Comment: None of the words you mention refer to the "type of [a] period between recurring events". A period is a duration. Those words refer to recurring points in time, not to durations (periods). The interval between the points is referred to indirectly by the names.

Answer (score 2):

This EL&U question calls it [lengths of time](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/18540/3306).

This SAP blog calls it an [interval](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3271131). ("interval report daily, monthly, weekly, quarterly, yearly in crystal report")

Searching for a hypernym for *time period* yields: "The categorization of the past into discrete, quantified named blocks of time is called [periodization](http://www.babylon-software.com/definition/time%20period)." But note that these are oriented toward much longer time periods, such as cosmological and geological eras (e.g., Cenozoic Era).

Searching for a hypernym for *period* yields: "[age, era; season; lesson; length of time](http://www.babylon-software.com/definition/period/English)."

Of the terms given, I think *interval* would be best understood. (*Age, era, and season* have other connotations; *lesson* does not apply in this context; *length of time* does not fit the single word criterion.) The process of choosing the interval would be *periodization*.

Comment: I agree it would be the most easily understood. I also think it would be the most commonly used phrase to describe these lengths of time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about the ***regularity*** of what these words are describing.

"*The regularity is daily/weekly/monthly...*"

> regularity noun [ U ] (REPEATED PATTERN)
>   ​
>
> the state or condition of having a fixed pattern, with equal or similar amounts of space or time between one and the next:
>   The regularity of the design gets boring after a while.

[- Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/regularity)

Answer (score 1):

A **recurrence** (as a short for recurrence pattern, which I believe more precise, although not a single word), used for instance in a [scheduler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41633_01/pt853pbh1/eng/pt/tprs/task_DefiningRecurrenceDefinitions-dc07fe.html).

Answer (score 0):

> what would be a generic term to categorize these words: *daily,
>   monthly, yearly, bimonthly, quarterly* etc.
>
> The word should mean "type of period between reoccurring events".

Those are two separate requirements:

- The period between reccurring events is called ***interval***;
- However, *daily, monthly, yearly, etc.* are ***frequencies***.

The *monthly* frequency has an interval of one *month*.

Answer (score 0):

*cycle*

I wish you would provide an example sentence, though, so I could test my word out in it.

Meaning: "a series of events that are regularly repeated in the same order" (google)